# Javascript username password userd system with proxy

Tags: javascript, php, proxy

Some service urls require username password parameter for security. In this stuations we recommended to use a proxy script on server. Do not use username password pairs in javascript applications. For example I have a service specified for me that url like this:

```
http://service.com/service?request=get&category=products&username=some&password=123456
```

This service dows not give me products witout username password pair.

I should create a proxy page with PHP, Aspx, Java or else. I create a proxy with PHP.

**`http://localhost/my/proxy.php`**

```
    $url = "http://service.com/service?request=get&category=products&username=some&password=123456";
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now I can use `http://localhost/my/proxy.php` in my javascript code. But everyone can send request to my proxy and get my products.  This is a problem yet. How can I solve this?

Comment: Require them to authenticate to your service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Allow only POST requests to the URL

   ```
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     // code
   }
   ```
2. Give a token (with cookies) for trusted users and check for the token before providing the service

   ```
   //setting the token
   setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);  

   //authentication
   if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) && $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] == $token){ 
     // code
   }
   ```
3. Use sessions instead of cookies

   ```
   //starting session mechanism
   session_start();

   //setting session
   $_SESSION['token'] = $token;

   //authentication
   if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $token){ 
     // code
   }
   ```